# What's in your developer toolbox?

Tags: tools

I'm newish to Salesforce and I'm curious about what frameworks/tools/products you use other than the standard development tools Salesforce provides (Force IDE, Developer Console) to accomplish your work.

When does it make sense to adopt these other tools? (team size, project type and complexity)

Which tools are providing the best value?

What should I build vs. buy?

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. This question is way to broad to provide any value to the community.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your response. I think newbies would benefit from an overview of the general tools landscape. Are there any must have or nice to have 3rd party tools for Salesforce?

Comment: Sublime Text with Mavensmate plugin works great.

Comment: Meh - Sublime/MM is the entry level good enough option, Illuminated Cloud with IntelliJ Idea is da bomb.....Really come down to preference/skill level/needs though

Comment: @ArpiJakab - While you are correct, this site is not designed to be a goto for general information about SF development. SFSE is limited to troubleshooting your code/issues. Plenty of blogs/sites out there covering the "general needs"

Answer (score -1):

IlluminatedCloud plugin for IntelliJ is the best IDE in my opinion. Well worth the purchase price. Other tools you need to know how to use are Data Loader and Workbench.